# i want to make the minutes add up but it seems to not work

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have no clue why its not working I have tried group by and order by but it doesn't seem to accept it can you double check and tell me what I need to do Thanks

code

```
CREATE TABLE todo_list (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, item TEXT, minutes INTEGER);
INSERT INTO todo_list VALUES (1, "Wash the dishes", 15);
INSERT INTO todo_list VALUES (2, "vacuuming", 20);
INSERT INTO todo_list VALUES (3, "Learn some stuff on KA", 30);
INSERT INTO todo_list VAlUES (4, "netflix", 12);
SELECT item, SUM(minutes) FROM todo_list GROUP BY item;
```

I been using a example from khan academy and an error shows up 
Error: Hm, are you sure you're selecting the total sum of the minutes across all of the items?

Can you tell me what I can do to fix it . thanks

Comment: You need to not `GROUP BY item` if you want the total across *all* items.

Comment: it seems ok, the elements that you entered there is no repetition.

Comment: try to insert a new element for example INSERT INTO  todo_list VALUES ('5',  'vacuuming',  '10'); and execute your command you will see that vacuuming now is showing 30

Comment: What are you getting back as opposed to desired results? You didn't say. I also don't see where you're echoing that.

Comment: There are too many tags used. Please only use ones that are relevant.

Comment: *"and an error shows up"* - What is the *exact* error? Your question is way too unclear. I'm voting to close as such. We're not behind you you know.

Comment: Are PHP and wordpress related? Seems like just a mysql question. Also `phpmyadmin` rarely is related to a SQL issue, that is a UI for accessing mysql.

Comment: oh ok i didnt know i am kinda new sorry